# TypeError: Error #1009 Actionscript 3 loading external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I started working on a flash shoot em-up game tutorial and i finished it [Asgamer Shoot em upp Game](http://asgamer.com/2009/flash-game-design-basics-adding-library-objects-to-stage-with-as3) 

Now i started creating a new .fla that is the Main Menu and i have a play button so when i press it it will load the .swf(Game swf) but when i press the button i get the following error.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 -at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject/construct()
 -at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject()
 -at com.actionscript.Ergasia::Ship()
 -at com.actionscript.Ergasia::Engine()





public function Engine() : void {
    if(stage) {
        initialize();
    } else {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
    }
} 

    private function initialize(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
        //  here goes the code that's currently in Engine constructor
    }
```

EDIT: Thanks to Viper for solving this!

Comment: Most likely your game SWF was created with `stage` already assigned, while in this content its `stage` property is yet null, as it's loaded but not added anywhere. So, wherever you address `stage` in your game SWF, make an `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` listener, and put all code that accesses stage in there, also don't allow proceeding while stage is null. Also, it's not enough to initiate loading the SWF, you ave to wait until it'll complete loading.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick answer, 
because i m beginner in as3 where do i put Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE?

Comment: That depends on what parts of code, and what classes refer to stage from within their constructor. At the very least it's `Ship` class. Do revise your entire codebase for constructors that call for `stage.something` inside them, these will net you a 1009 error if you let them. Instead, slap a `if (stage) init(null); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);` line at the end of each of these, and implement a `function init(e:Event):void { removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init); ...}` that will process whatever your class needs from stage.

Comment: Sorry again i edited my question so you can see the code from my Engine() class and the code you gave me so i can understand how can i change it

Comment: So, your `Engine` class has a pre-placed instance on the stage at design time. Right, this is a common issue of addressing stage in constructors. Yes, you need to do exactly this, except for making `Engine()` return void - it's still a constructor. So, `public function Engine() {` instead of `: void`.

Comment: `public function Engine() {` i change that and still i get the 1009 error

Comment: The context of error is the same, `in Engine() in Ship()`, or elsewhere?

Comment: and on `at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject/construct()
 at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject()` i have posted the the two .as Engine and Ship and i cant figure how to insert the code you gave me.

Comment: Actually, you do just that: replace constructor header with `private function initialize(e:Event = null):void`, add removeEventListener statement as first line, then add a new constructor as you wrote it, and check. Also update the question if you'll get another 1009.

Comment: is it possible to edit my code because i m kinda lost of what to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Engine` constructor to the following:

```
public function Engine() {
    if(stage) {
        initialize();
        } else  addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
    } 

private function initialize(e:Event = null):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
    //  here goes the code that was in Engine constructor
    trace(stage);
        ourShip = new Ship(stage);
        stage.addChild(ourShip);
        ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        ourShip.addEventListener("hit", shipHit, false, 0, true);
        stage.addChild(ourShip);
        scoreHUD = new ScoreHUD(stage);
        stage.addChild(scoreHUD);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numCloud; i++)
        {
            stage.addChildAt(new Cloud(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourShip));

        }
        for (var b:int = 0; b < numStar; b++)
        {
            stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourShip));
        }

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
}
```

The main problem is that your `Engine` class is written in presumption that `stage` is already accessible, but when you load the SWF, its `stage` is null while that SWF is not added to the stage. To circumvent this, the common practice is using the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` listener, and start placing your code in there instead of the constructor.

Comment: To mark a question as solved, click a "tick" under the answer that helped you the most. This helps improving StackOverflow as a community, and increases chances that someone would answer your future questions.